# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, json

I have this application where I am trying to pass a list to another class. I keep getting the error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<eko_app.LoginForm.Business>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<eko_app.GlobalClass.Business>'
```

The list is generated from Json.

### Login class

```
   private void Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                serverUrl = "https://eko-app.com/Users/login/username:" + usernameEntered + "/password:" + passwordEntered + ".json";

                var w = new WebClient();
                var jsonData = string.Empty;

                // make the login api call
                jsonData = w.DownloadString(serverUrl);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData))
                {
                    // deserialize the json to c# .net
                    var response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonData);

                    // Get the sessionId
                    GlobalClass.SessionId = string.Empty;
                    GlobalClass.SessionId = response.response.SessionId;

                    if (GlobalClass.SessionId != null)
                    {                      
                        var businesses = response.response.Businesses;

                        GlobalClass.Username = "";
                        GlobalClass.Username = usernameEntered;                        

                        GlobalClass.Businesses = null;
                        GlobalClass.Businesses = businesses; **<-----error thrown here**

                        HomeForm homeForm = new HomeForm();
                        this.Hide();
                        homeForm.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Login failed");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private class Business
        {
            public string businessID { get; set; }
            public string businessName { get; set; }
        }

        private class Response
        {
            [JsonProperty("sessionId")]
            public string SessionId { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("businesses")]    
            public List<Business> Businesses { get; set; }
        }

        private class Messages
        {
            public string sessionId { get; set; }
            public List<Business> businesses { get; set; }
        }

        private class RootObject
        {
            public Response response { get; set; }
            public Messages messages { get; set; }
        }
```

I have another class: Global Class

```
namespace eko_app
{
    static class GlobalClass
    {
       ...some code     

        public class Business
        {
            private string businessID { get; set; }
            private string businessName { get; set; }
        }

        private static List<Business> businesses = null;

        public static List<Business> Businesses
        {
            get { return businesses; }
            set { businesses = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The error is thrown in the first class at   `GlobalClass.Businesses = businesses;`

Comment: @Sachin What's wrong with that?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Usually nothing, though I find this `GlobalClass` arrangement highly suspect in this case...

Comment: @David Yep, I agree with you.This is poor or shows naive design. But his comment sounds like questioning it is not possible or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you have two identical classes called `Business` - one nested inside your `GlobalClass`, and the other nested inside your `LoginForm`.

Although both classes look the same, they are not assignable to each other. Moreover, collections based on these classes are not assignable to each other either.

Consider dropping one of these classes (e.g. the private one in the `LoginForm`) and replace all its uses with `GlobalClass.Business`, which is public.

Comment: Possible solutions: create an explicit/implicit converter, only use one class and remove the other, use AutoMapper or simply create a new object with the fields of the previous object.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel You missed easy solution: To reuse the same type

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Better yet, remove one of these classes, and use the other instead. The `GlobalClass.Business` looks like a good candidate to me.

Comment: Yeah, I added it a second later. Removing one is the easiest and probably best, but it seems so straightforward that this might not be a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

You have two completely different classes, both of which happen to be named `Business`.  One here:

```
static class GlobalClass
{
    public class Business
    {
        private string businessID { get; set; }
        private string businessName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and one here:

```
public class LoginForm
{
    private class Business
    {
        public string businessID { get; set; }
        public string businessName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Even though these two classes are *mostly* identical, they statically compile to two completely different things.  No amount of similar naming will change that.

You *could* write methods to convert one to another, but that will probably just hide the problem instead of actually solve it.  I imagine what you want to do is choose which one is your actual `Business` class and use only that.  So you might deprecate the second one and change the `Response` property to something like:

```
public List<GlobalClass.Business> Businesses { get; set; }
```